# values not inserting in other table

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
    DELIMITER $$
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ravi.`after_insert`$$
    CREATE
   /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
   TRIGGER `ravi`.`after_insert` AFTER UPDATE
  ON `ravi`.`user_data`
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN`
 IF(NEW.field1 !=OLD.field1)THEN
 INSERT INTO logs_data(uri,field_id,old_value,new_value,modified_date)
 VALUES(NEW.uri,"filed1",OLD.field1,NEW.field1,NOW());
 END IF;
 IF(NEW.field2!=OLD.field2)THEN
 INSERT INTO logs_date(uri,field_id,old_value,new_value,modified_date)
 VALUES(NEW.uri,"field2",OLD.field2,NEW.field2,NOW());
 END IF;
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

values are not inserting in second table but trigger is running
   trigger is not working

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you've meant to use **[`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)** statement instead of **[`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)** function
2. a name for the trigger `after_insert` is confusing since you're using `AFTER UPDATE` event
3. there are also a couple of typos `'filed1'` instead of `'field1'` and more importantly `log_date` instead of `log_data` in second `INSERT` statement.

That being said your trigger should probably look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER user_data_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON user_data
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.field1 != OLD.field1 THEN
        INSERT INTO logs_data(uri, field_id, old_value, new_value, modified_date)
        VALUES(NEW.uri, 'field1', OLD.field1, NEW.field1, NOW());
    END IF;
    IF NEW.field2 != OLD.field2 THEN
        INSERT INTO logs_data(uri, field_id, old_value, new_value, modified_date)
        VALUES(NEW.uri, 'field2', OLD.field2, NEW.field2, NOW());
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/537004/1)** demo